# How do I control the onCompletion() method in the service class

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a Service n UI class the Service class has the mediaplayer n onCompletion methods to see keep track of a completed song.
Well the problem is how do I notify the UI about the completion of the song from the Service class so that it changes its details according to the new song that is now going to be played?
.

Answer (score 1):

Use a callback through a custom interface. You then give this interface to the service and call it when needed.

```
public interface CallOnComplete
{
    public void updateUi();
}
```

Then, inside your activity where you create your service, give an instance of this interface doing the work you wanted to the service, and call it when the mediaplayer completes.
I'm not sure this will be counted as running in the UIThread, if there is any problem you can always use the view.post() to ensure it does.

```
//IF YOU HAVE TO UPDATE THE ACTIVITY'S VIEWS
private CallOnComplete callback = new CallOnComplete(){
    public void updateUI()
    {
        viewToModify.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                //UPDATE VIEW
            }
        });
    }
};

//ANYTHING ELSE
private CallOnComplete callback = new CallOnComplete(){
    public void updateUI()
    {
        //UPDATE ANYTHING YOU HAVE TO UPDATE
    }
};
```

Then inside the service you can call

```
mCallback.updateUI();
```

Or you can always use Intents or simply call a static method inside the activity, just be sure to use post() as modifying views in a different thread will crash the app.